# read and write same file bash/unix

Tags: bash, unix, recursion

I have a list of `keys` which are listed in a txt file

sample.txt
    `address
    contact_id
    created_at
    creator_id
    custom_fields
    address
    contact_id
    phone
    name
    email
    name`

I have the following recursive script which can remove duplicates

```
#!/bin/bash
function keyChecker(){
    if grep -q $i uniqueKeys.txt; then
        echo "Duplicate Key: ${i}"
    else
        echo $i >> uniqueKeys.txt
         echo "New key: ${i}"
    fi
}

function recursiveDoer(){
    for i in $(cat keys.txt); do
        keyChecker $i
    done
recursiveDoer
}
touch uniqueKeys.txt
counter=0
recursiveDoer
```

This code will return a unique list of keys to `uniqueKeys.txt`

These methods will send into an infinite loop once there are no more duplicates. Every recursive method I have wrote runs into this problem. I usually cheat by adding a counter that forces an `exit 1` after an arbitrarily large number like `10,000`.

1. What is the proper way to write this method using recursion and no infinite loop?
2. Can this be simplified and written as a non-recursive method in a single loop?

Comment: You don't need recursion here. Remove the call inside the function, the `for` loop checks all keys and this is the end.

Comment: Actually that is not true, if you do that, you will find that it will treat all keys as new keys. I believe this is caused by not closing the file. Further testing needed

Comment: You really do not need a recursive function here. However, you should change both instances of `$i` in `keychecker` to `$1` (or better yet to `"$1"`) since you apparently expect `keychecker` to check its argument. (Also in the echoed strings. `${i}` is unnecessary; just use `$1`.)

Comment: rici, those comments don't actually help with my problem. All you have done is describe a different way to reference my arguement.... You did not solve the recursion issue. Please keep comments to recursion issues

Comment: That is why it is a comment and not an answer :) However, "the recursion is unnecessary" is, in fact, an accurate statement. The file is not kept open between iterations.

Comment: After changing `keys.txt` to `sample.txt` in `recursiveDoer` and removing the recursive call, the function worked perfectly. Presumably, it is not quite as you have presented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this `awk` magic will only print the unique entries in the same order

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

you can overwrite the input file with this idiom

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file > temp && mv temp file
```

this probably replicates your code

```
awk '!a[$0]++ {print "New key: " $0;
               print > "uniqueKeys.txt"
               next}
              {print "Duplicate Key: " $0}' file
```

**Explanation**

> `a[$0]` creates an entry in the associative map `a` for the read line as the key.  `++` forces the null value to be treated as 0 and increments. `!` forces the value to be treated as Boolean and negates it.  Taken all together, it will be only true for the first time the key is seen, therefore effectively de-duplicating the lines in the file.

Comment: could you please clarify what `!a[$0]++` is doing?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about the order of the keys you can simply use

`sort -u keys.txt > uniqueKeys.txt`

Comment: great answer, though for my usecase I  do need them to be in order as they are later associated with value pairs.